# Populating tableView rows with data from plist

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, plist

Disclaimer: New to swift coding but not new to coding world

Getting the devices as the section header; but not able to get companies as the rows inside the tableView. 
How should i get the company names to be populated inside the tableView rows corresponding to the devices type

```
import UIKit

class MainPageViewController: UITableViewController {
 var devices = [AnyObject]()

 let CellIdentifier = "Cell Identifier"

var companyName: [AnyObject] {
    if let companyName = devices["Comp"] as? [AnyObject] {
        return companyName
    } else {
        return [AnyObject]()
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    title = "Devices"

    let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Array", ofType: "plist")
    if let path = filePath {
        devices = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) as! [AnyObject]
    }
    print(device)
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier)
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return devices.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    var titleName = title
    if let deviceHeader = devices[section] as? [String: AnyObject], let titled = deviceHeader["Device"] as? String
    {
        titleName = titled
    }
    return titleName
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return companyName.count
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    if let company = companyName[indexPath.row] as? [String: AnyObject], let name = company["Company"] as? String {
        cell.textLabel?.text = name
    }

    return cell;
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
```

The plist file

```
    <array>
    <dict>
        <key>Device</key>
        <string>Smartphones</string>
        <key>Comp</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>Company</key>
                <string>Apple</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Company</key>
                <string>Samsung</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Device</key>
        <string>Notebooks</string>
        <key>Comp</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>Company</key>
                <string>HP</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Company</key>
                <string>Dell</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Company</key>
                <string>Lenovo</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

Comment: override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 0  // here add some value like devices.count
}

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya added companyName.count but not able to get the data yet

Comment: Please copy and paste real code.

Comment: @rmaddy done that

Comment: @Dar print your device that i add in viewdidload()

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya devices ? It didnt help

Comment: i want to show your data type and data so i made change in your tableview delagates method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is updated code:

```
var devices = [AnyObject]()
    let CellIdentifier = "Cell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        title = "Devices"
        let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Array", ofType: "plist")
        if let path = filePath {
            devices = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) as! [AnyObject]
        }
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier)
    }
    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return devices.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        var titleName = title
        if let deviceHeader = devices[section] as? [String: AnyObject], let titled = deviceHeader["Device"] as? String
        {
            titleName = titled
        }
        return titleName
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        guard let device  = devices[section] as? [String: AnyObject], let companies = device["Comp"] as? [AnyObject] else {
            return 0
        }
        return companies.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CellIdentifier, for: indexPath)

        guard let device  = devices[indexPath.section] as? [String: AnyObject], let companies = device["Comp"] as? [AnyObject] else {
            return cell
        }
        guard let company = companies[indexPath.row] as? [String: AnyObject] else {
            return cell
        }
        cell.textLabel?.text = company["Company"] as? String
        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: It worked perfectly ... I have a doubt on why guard let is used ?

Comment: guard is used to avoid nested if else structure. You can read more  here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html

Comment: what will be the code if i make comp directly as an array of strings containing the company names ?

Comment: Don't just post a bunch of code. Clearly explain what was wrong and how your answer solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this one please.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let dict = devices[section]
    let array = dic["comp"]    
    return array.count
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CellIdentifier, for: indexPath)

    let dict = devices[section]
    let array = dic["comp"]  
     if let companyname = array[indexPath.row] {
        cell.textLabel?.text = companyname
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: return array.count is forcing me to convert into return array!!.count

Comment: and the func tableView isnt working; Showing an error cannot subscript a value of tyep anyobject with an index of type section

Comment: @Dar firstly I tried to get Device dictionary by section after that try to get an array of companies by 'comp' key after getting array of companies I can get the required company name by indexPath.row. Hopefully you understand my approach. If you problem can solve by updating me suggested code then please do it.

Answer (score -2):

Try change this code ,

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
```

like this,

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CellIdentifier)
```